# facebook social share need to be login

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm using facebook social share, calling facebook SDK as following.

```
 var data = { app_id: "myappid123"
    caption: "caption"
    description: "description"
    href: "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mySite.info%2Fblog%2Fpost"
    method: "share"
    name: "name"
    picture: "http://my.png"
    redirect_uri: "http://www.mySite.info/"
    }
     FB.ui(data, function (response) {
            });
```

However I noticed i have to login as my app_id's facebook account so I could share, if I'm not login to facebook as my app_id's account I can't share.

Do I missing some other authentication by doing this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is your facebook app is in developers mode. Check your app setting if it shows something like following
[App in developer mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfGX9.png)
Then you need to make it public by clicking the question mark at the end of developer mode message, provide contact email address and making it public. After that you can login with any facebook account to share.